# Gracenote Entourage Error 130/74

Tags: gracenote

I first created my Gracenote developer account last night, and without issue, was able to match TV shows using the sample applications.

However today, I'm receiving the following error continuously:

```
ERROR GCSP: Hello error: [130] Please contact Gracenote ODP 06176 [Name: Mark Pringle] [App: Echos Imterface] support.
[Gracenote Error 130/74] (0x90160165)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The GNSDK error code is the last 4 digits of the hex number at the end. If you check out the gnsdk_error_codes.h file, you can see that 0165 is GNSDKERR_InvalidClientID.

Assuming you are still setting your ID correctly, I am not sure why such an error would be returned by the servers.  I could hazard some guesses (maybe you went so far past your quotas that they blocked it?) but I don't really know.

Either way, I would recommend getting a new client ID from the Gracenote dev site and see if that works.

hope this helps!