# Gracenote Web API is failing on ALBUM_TOC query

Tags: gracenote

I have been using the Gracenote Web API in an application for the last year without any issues. Suddenly a couple weeks ago, my application stopped working. I am receiving the following error in response to a simple ALBUM_TOC query:

```
<RESPONSES>
  <MESSAGE>GCSP: Hello error: [130] Please contact Gracenote ODP 00431 [Name: ***** *******] [App: ********] support.
[Gracenote Error     130/74]</MESSAGE>
 <RESPONSE STATUS="ERROR">
 </RESPONSE>
</RESPONSES>
```

I have no idea what this means. The developer site hasn't been any help, and there doesn't seem to be any way to "contact Gracenote ODP" (at least no way that I can find).

I found [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625255/gracenote-entourage-error-130-74), which appears to be strongly related to my issue. However, I get no hex number that I can look up. Also, when I attempt to create a new app on developer.gracenote.com, the only option I am given is to choose the Entourage platform, which is of no use to me.

Any idea how I can resolve this error?

(One other key point: this is a personal app, and one that I didn't use for several weeks before encountering the error, so it can't possibly be a quota issue.)

Comment: Sorry you're getting errors. To help, we'd like to know your Client ID, but please don't post it on Stack Overflow. If you can post a question to https://developer.gracenote.com/forums/music-web-api we can look you up and get in touch with you directly.

Comment: Thanks, cweichen. I posted the question in the music-web-api forum using the same title as this SO post.